# How do Wayland and Xorg server get keyboard and mouse input?

Tags: linux, wayland

Do they open /dev files directly? If so, wouldn't they need *root* permission to do that?

This is a little off topic, but if you were to write a Wayland compositor from scratch, would you have to handle input directly yourself (vs. using a library like Xlib on Xorg)?

Answer (score 0):

I may expand on this later but I think Wikipedia answers your question well:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev